# find and press a button on a webpage using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i am not able to find the key of the search button. i am trying to enter "computer" and click the search button. I am able to find the name of the input box but none for the search buttton. 
I find the code below on internet and modify some of the variable names. The code below is able to navigate to bestbuy.com and input the text "computer" on the search box. However, i stuck at writing the code for clicking the search button. Please help me out.

My vba code:

```
Sub searching()
Set a = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
a.Visible = True
a.navigate ("http://www.bestbuy.com")
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until a.readyState = 4
a.document.all("st").Value = "computer"
a.document.all("search").Click
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objie.readyState = 4
End Sub
```

the html code for the search button:

```html
<div class="search-bar" role="search">
<form action="http://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp" name="frmSearch" method="GET">
<label for="gh-search-input">Search Best Buy</label>
<span class="clear-icon"><a href='#clear' class='clear-search-icon'>clear</a> </span>
<input type="text" value="" name="st" maxlength="90" placeholder="Search Best Buy" id="gh-search-input" /><button type="submit" class="search-button" aria-label="Search" title="Search">
<span class="header-icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
<input type="hidden" value="UTF-8" name="_dyncharset" />
<input type="hidden" value="pcat17071" name="id"/>
<input type="hidden" value="page" name="type" />
<input type="hidden" value="Global" name="sc" />
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="cp" />
<input type="hidden" value="" name="nrp" />
<input type="hidden" value="" name="sp" />
<input type="hidden" value="" name="qp" />
<input type="hidden" value="n" name="list" />
<input type="hidden" value="y" name="iht" />
<input type="hidden" value="All Categories" name="usc" />
<input type="hidden" value="960" name="ks" />
<input id="keys" type="hidden" value="keys" name="keys">
</form>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: `<button type="submit" class="search-button" aria-label="Search" title="Search">`
     `<span class="header-icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>`
     `</button>`

That's the code from bestbuy's website's search button. As you see, no id is used at all.

All you have to do is open the bestbuy website, press f12 to open the console and highlight the button.

Maybe try using the class name to find the element. I don't think there are more than one button with that class.

Comment: thanks jitendra garg. i am looking into the code again try to use the getelement by class.

Answer (score 0):

parse the search text to get the search result

```
Sub check()
    Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim anchorElement As HTMLAnchorElement
    Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
    Dim ie As Variant
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    searchtext = "Computer" '----Parse your Search Text here
    ie.navigate "http://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?st=" & searchtext & "&_dyncharset=UTF-8&id=pcat17071&type=page&sc=Global&cp=1&nrp=&sp=&qp=&list=n&iht=y&usc=All+Categories&ks=960&keys=keys"
    While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE And ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_LOADED
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:3"))
End Sub
```

Comment: karthick thank you so much for your code. Your code did what i want. However, i want to understand the concept how do you come up with (http://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?st=" & searchtext & "&_dyncharset=UTF-8&id=pcat17071&type=page&sc=Global&cp=1&nrp=&sp=&qp=&list=n&iht=y&usc=All+Categories&ks=960&keys=keys ).
plus i want to know if i want to click the search button. how should i code it?
Again thanks so much for your time and help.

Comment: No id is used for search button. I tried with Class name it does not worked out. hence i gathered the url (static) of search class and parse the text in to it.

Comment: thanks karthick, i understand the concept now. thanks for helping.